# Debian 7 PHP update 5.6.4

Tags: php, linux, debian, updates

I'm trying to update my php from 5.6.31 to 5.6.4 I have looked and looked I cannot seem to find a guide anywhere 
However I did find a guide to install 5.6.31 (Which I had thought would've been 5.6.4)

Comment: Last time I checked, 31 is greater than 4 ;)

Comment: The developer of a software I'm trying to use says I need to update php from 5.6.31 to 5.6.4

Comment: That developer doesn't sound like they know what they're talking about. Going from 5.6.31 to 5.6.4 isn't an update, it's a downgrade. 5.6.31 is the latest stable version of PHP 5.6 at the moment.

Comment: That would be a down-grade, not an upgrade.

Comment: You should definitely check what PHP versions are provided as stable packages for the desired Debian version at https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=Php5 ... it is 5.4.45 for Wheezy (7) and 5.6.30 for Jessie (8)

Comment: Please don't ask for tutorials. You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I'm also pretty sure "How do I perform system maintenance task <X>" is off-topic here as well. Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. There are two other StackExchange site for questions about Linux (and Unix).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any update problem, you can resolve with purging/installing any package again:

```
apt-get purge php.*
```

Installing

```
apt-get install php<desired_version>
```

Comment: apt-get install php5.6.4    is this correct?

Comment: First, check if it exists with apt-get search php*

Comment: Then you can use that.

Comment: root@vmi121314:~# apt-get search php*
E: Invalid operation search

Comment: (I'm newish to linux)

Comment: remove the *: apt-get search php